# How to get a value from an Object that comes from a ManyToOne relationship in Angular CLI?

Tags: html, angular, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot, Angular CLI and mySQL.

I have an Employee than can have one Marital Status, and one M Status can be in N Employees.

In localHost:8080 I get the right array json:

```
[{"id":1,"firstName":"Name","lastName":"surname1","emailAddress":"test@test1.com","status":{"statusId":1,"nameStatus":"Single"}
```

In my angular table(localHost:4200), instead I get every data but in Status column I get "[object Object]".

In have a service for each one.

When I do a registration I have a dropDown w/ all status so I get them.

This is my HTML table:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th *ngFor="let col of columns">{{col}}
    </th>
    <th>Actions</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let employee of employees | paginate: {itemsPerPage: pageSize,
                                           currentPage: page,
                                           totalItems: employees.length}  | filterAll: searchString : field">
    <td *ngFor="let col of columns">{{employee[col]}}</td>
    <td>
      <button [ngClass]="getClassCondition(act.actionType)" *ngFor="let act of actions"
              (click)="actionFunc(act, employee)">{{act.label}}</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here I have an ngFor that gets All employees.

Now I share also my services and my componets.ts:

status.service.ts:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StatusService {

  private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api';

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient) { }

  getStatus(): Observable<Status[]> {
    return this.http.get<Status[]>(`${this.baseUrl}` + '/status');
  }
}
```

employee.service.ts

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class EmployeeService {

  columns = COLUMNS;
  actions = ACTIONS;

  private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/employees';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getColumns() {
    return this.columns;
  }

  getActions() {
    return this.actions;
  }

  getMetadata() {
    return this.metadata;
  }

  /** GET Employees from the server */
  getEmployees(): Observable<Employee[]> {
    return this.http.get<Employee[]>(this.baseUrl);
  }

  getEmployee(id: number): Observable<Employee> {
    const url = this.baseUrl + '/' + id;
    return this.http.get<Employee>(url);
  }

  /** PUT: update the employee on the server */
  updateEmployee(employee: Employee): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.put(`${this.baseUrl}/${employee.id}`, employee, httpOptions);
  }

  deleteEmployee(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.delete(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`, {responseType: 'text'});
  }

}
```

Here I have also a const w/ COLUMNS name.
employee.ts

```
export const COLUMNS = ['id', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'emailAddress', 'status'];

export class Employee {
  id: number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  emailAddress: string;
  status: string;
}
```

status.ts

```
export class Status {
  statusId: number;
  nameStatus: string;
}
```

What do I have to do to get my status.Name?
Is there something specific?

If you need more documentation ask me.

Comment: please post the code for you `.ts` also

Comment: @SachinGupta edited

Comment: Hello, can you add the part of th `.ts` where you merge the two observables ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that *col* return *status* and *employee[col]* return `{"statusId":1,"nameStatus":"Single"}`.

So the error seems correct.

You can do a workaround here if you just want to display the nameStatus :

```
<td *ngFor="let col of columns">{{employee[col]?.nameStatus ? employee[col]?.nameStatus : employee[col]}}</td>
```

Comment: ok, this is the right solution but when I have a row w/ no status it didn't show in the table and I get this error in console:

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nameStatus' of undefined

Comment: As @Stefan suggest, you can do `<td>{{employee?.status?.nameStatus}}</td>`, with the question mark to avoid the null pointer. 
I have edited my solution.

Comment: can I do the same w/ a ManyToMany?
example: I also have skills w/ name and Id, different service like status and in my employee.ts I added   "skillList: Skill[];". 

How can I do the same for print it in my table?

Comment: Not really. This is a workarround because it works only if there is one object (status). With multiple object, you will have to chose a different strategy.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be more specific, how you display the data or map the data to the structure you want

1) instead of `<td *ngFor="let col of columns">{{employee[col]}}</td>`
you can do

```
<td>{{employee.firstName}}</td>
<td>{{employee.lastName}}</td>
...
<td>{{employee.status.nameStatus}}</td>
```

2) before binding the data, map it to the structure you want (in your controller/*.ts file).
Take a look at [Array map(](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp) for that.

Your code doesn't seem to work because the controller never assigns the employee method

Comment: I knew this solution but my table must to be dynamic, so If I add a column in my service I will be able to edit just the component.